# How to put 3 and 4 figures side by side html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have 3 figures side by side, each containing an image (that has a link in it), and a caption that's centered on the top of the image.

So far, I've got this:

```css
figure {
  display: table;
  width: 50%;
  margin:0;
}

figcaption {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: top;
}

#content {
  max-width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="center">

    <div>
      <figure style="float:left;">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/26392d05302e02f7bf4eb143bb84c8097d09144b/446_167_3683_2210/master/3683.jpg?width=445&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=42132184edabf489cb379824f3da6f61" loading="lazy" alt="cat" width="30%">
        </a>
        <figcaption style="text-align:center">Cute cat </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/26392d05302e02f7bf4eb143bb84c8097d09144b/446_167_3683_2210/master/3683.jpg?width=445&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=42132184edabf489cb379824f3da6f61" loading="lazy" alt="cat 2" width="30%">
        </a>
        <figcaption style="text-align:center">Cute cat 2 </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>

  </div>
```

But when I try to add a third (or fourth, for that matter) image, the whole thing malfunctions.
I've tried using `style="float:right;` on the third image, which leads to it being below the other 2 figures on another line(of course, after reducing the width of `figure` first).

Essentially what I want the end result to be is to be able to put any number of images (3 and 4 for my use, but generalizing the solution will help people with the same problem) side by side, while each image has some text over it (hence the `figure` and `figcaption` CSS rules, which display the `figcaption` above the picture)

Comment: You might want to look into using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

Comment: Also why are some styles on a seperate style sheet and some on the elements themselves? I would recommend separating these, or it will be difficult to maintain the code down the road.

Comment: So, you are suggesting I make each figure a flex box and move that around? Makes sense, will test that. Also,  Ik it's ugly to have styles both on the elements as well as a separate sheet, but I do that in a draft, to be quick, and fix it down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.flex{display: flex;}
figure {
  display: table;
  width: 50%;
  margin:0;
}

figcaption {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: top;
}

#content {
  max-width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="center">

    <div class="flex">
      <figure >
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/26392d05302e02f7bf4eb143bb84c8097d09144b/446_167_3683_2210/master/3683.jpg?width=445&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=42132184edabf489cb379824f3da6f61" loading="lazy" alt="cat" width="30%">
        </a>
        <figcaption style="text-align:center">Cute cat </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure >
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/26392d05302e02f7bf4eb143bb84c8097d09144b/446_167_3683_2210/master/3683.jpg?width=445&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=42132184edabf489cb379824f3da6f61" loading="lazy" alt="cat" width="30%">
        </a>
        <figcaption style="text-align:center">Cute cat </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure >
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/26392d05302e02f7bf4eb143bb84c8097d09144b/446_167_3683_2210/master/3683.jpg?width=445&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=42132184edabf489cb379824f3da6f61" loading="lazy" alt="cat" width="30%">
        </a>
        <figcaption style="text-align:center">Cute cat </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure >
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/26392d05302e02f7bf4eb143bb84c8097d09144b/446_167_3683_2210/master/3683.jpg?width=445&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=42132184edabf489cb379824f3da6f61" loading="lazy" alt="cat" width="30%">
        </a>
        <figcaption style="text-align:center">Cute cat </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/26392d05302e02f7bf4eb143bb84c8097d09144b/446_167_3683_2210/master/3683.jpg?width=445&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=42132184edabf489cb379824f3da6f61" loading="lazy" alt="cat 2" width="30%">
        </a>
        <figcaption style="text-align:center">Cute cat 2 </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Are you aware of any way to enlarge the image so that it "fills" the figure, at least width-wise? I can do `width=150%` and enlarge the image, but I am almost certain there's another way to do it, without making width more than 100%.

Comment: `transform: scale(2);`

Answer (score 0):

For 3-4 image you can provide width to the element. But you can show a defined number of images using width. To show n number of image you can show as table and use css property `overflaw:scroll`.

```css
figure {
  display: table;
  width: 50%;
  margin:0;
}

figcaption {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: top;
}

#content {
  max-width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="center">

    <div>
      <figure style="float:left; width:25%">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/26392d05302e02f7bf4eb143bb84c8097d09144b/446_167_3683_2210/master/3683.jpg?width=445&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=42132184edabf489cb379824f3da6f61" loading="lazy" alt="cat" width="30%">
        </a>
        <figcaption style="text-align:center">Cute cat </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure style="float:left; width:25%">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/26392d05302e02f7bf4eb143bb84c8097d09144b/446_167_3683_2210/master/3683.jpg?width=445&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=42132184edabf489cb379824f3da6f61" loading="lazy" alt="cat 2" width="30%">
        </a>
        <figcaption style="text-align:center">Cute cat 2 </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure style="float:left; width:25%">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/26392d05302e02f7bf4eb143bb84c8097d09144b/446_167_3683_2210/master/3683.jpg?width=445&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=42132184edabf489cb379824f3da6f61" loading="lazy" alt="cat" width="30%">
        </a>
        <figcaption style="text-align:center">Cute cat </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure style="float:left; width:25%">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/26392d05302e02f7bf4eb143bb84c8097d09144b/446_167_3683_2210/master/3683.jpg?width=445&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=42132184edabf489cb379824f3da6f61" loading="lazy" alt="cat 2" width="30%">
        </a>
        <figcaption style="text-align:center">Cute cat 2 </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Ow, that completely slipped my mind when making this, thanks. Can the images be resized somehow, so that each one "fills" its figure, at least width-wise? `width=150%` is a solution, but I feel there's another one, where you don't have to exceed 100%.

Answer (score 0):

firstly remove float and use **display: flex;**, it is very useful and highly recommended one.

and change the code to like this

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.item {
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
.image-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.caption {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <div id="container">
      <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="link">
                <h3 class="caption">Cute cat </h3>
              <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/26392d05302e02f7bf4eb143bb84c8097d09144b/446_167_3683_2210/master/3683.jpg?width=445&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=42132184edabf489cb379824f3da6f61" loading="lazy" alt="cat" class="image-container">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="link">
                <h3 class="caption">Cute cat </h3>
              <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/26392d05302e02f7bf4eb143bb84c8097d09144b/446_167_3683_2210/master/3683.jpg?width=445&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=42132184edabf489cb379824f3da6f61" loading="lazy" alt="cat" class="image-container">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" class="link">
                <h3 class="caption">Cute cat </h3>
              <img src="https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/26392d05302e02f7bf4eb143bb84c8097d09144b/446_167_3683_2210/master/3683.jpg?width=445&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=42132184edabf489cb379824f3da6f61" loading="lazy" alt="cat 2" class="image-container">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```